# Publish from Visual Studio and automatically encrypt appSettings using aspnet_regiis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, encryption, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-web-deploy

I have web application that is deployed to my local IIS server under `Sites\Default`, it works fine and right now I want to make it more secure - I want to encrypt connection strings and appSettings.
Inside pubxml file I've added this line:

```
<MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>true</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>
```

but that only encrypts connections strings.
I know that I can manually call:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -site Default -app "/"
```

on my server after deploy to encrypt external file containing appSettings, but I must do that manually.

My question is how can I deploy website from Visual Studio (Build > Publish) and have that `aspnet_regiis` command execute automatically after publish succeeded.

I [found information](http://forums.iis.net/t/1223409.aspx?Encrypting%20any%20section%20of%20Web%20Config) that I could use `runcommand` and [other about bat files](http://forums.iis.net/t/1223551.aspx?Execute%20a%20BAT%20file%20file%20using%20Web%20Deploy%20command%20line), but I'm not calling MSDeploy from command line.
I've also found information that I should build custom provider and call it from MSDeploy.

How should I edit my pubxml file to get this behaviour?

**EDIT1:**
I've managed to hook `After Deploy` Target using:

```
<Target Name="EncryptAppSettings" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >
  <Message Text="Encrypting appSettings" />
  <Exec Command="aspnet_regiis -pe &quot;appSettings&quot; -site Default -app &quot;/&quot;" />
  <Message Text="AppPath: $(DeployIisAppPath)" />
</Target>
```

But now I get this error:

> The command "aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -site Default -app "/""
>   exited with code 9009.

**EDIT2:**
I've tried using runCommand like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
    <path>aspnet_regiis -pe &quot;appSettings&quot; -site Default -app &quot;/&quot;</path>
    <waitInterval>10000</waitInterval>
    <AdditionalProviderSettings>waitInterval</AdditionalProviderSettings>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```

but I had no luck. [I found blog](http://blog.degree.no/tag/msdeploy/) about postSync:runCommand, but I'd like to call that directly from VS so I'd like to add that to publish profile.

**EDIT3:**
I'm adding my publish profile below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>192.168.5.50</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Default</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>True</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>
    <UserName>LocalAdmin</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="ApplicationDbContext" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="Data Source=192.168.5.51;Initial Catalog=GameBit;User ID=GUser;Password=MyRealPassword;Application Name=EntityFramework" Name="Data Source=192.168.5.51;Initial Catalog=GameBit;User ID=GUser;Password=MyRealPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="Api.ApplicationDbContext, Api" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseMsdeployExe>true</UseMsdeployExe>
    <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)ApplicationDbContext-Web.config Connection String">
      <ParameterValue>metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=192.168.5.51;Initial Catalog=GameBit;User ID=GUser;Password=MyRealPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"</ParameterValue>
    </MSDeployParameterValue>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
    <Path>dir</Path>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>-->


  <!--<Target Name="EncryptImportantSettings" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >
    <Message Text="Encrypting appSettings" />
    --><!--<Exec Command="aspnet_regiis -pe &quot;appSettings&quot; -site Default -app &quot;/&quot;" />--><!--
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
      <path>dir/b >> C:\temp\log.txt</path>
      --><!--<waitInterval>10000</waitInterval>--><!--
      --><!--<AdditionalProviderSettings>waitInterval</AdditionalProviderSettings>--><!--
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="AppPath: $(DeployIisAppPath)" />
  </Target>-->
</Project>
```

I've noticed that when I use MSDeploy I can see command that is executed during publish:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
>   -source:manifest='D:\GameBit\API\obj\Release\Package\API.SourceManifest.xml'
>   -dest:auto,ComputerName="https://192.168.5.50:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default",UserName='LocalAdmin',Password="MyRealPassword",IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic'
>   -verb:sync -enableRule:EncryptWebConfig -enableRule:EncryptWebConfig -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"D:\GameBit\API\obj\Release\Package\API.Publish.Parameters.xml"
>   -allowUntrusted -retryAttempts=2 -userAgent="VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0"

Can I add `-postSync:runCommand=""` to that command from publish profile? As [I found on MS site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831ddff2-54e7-4ceb-8b9d-54cc0ce17b7d) this parameter allows to execute command on destination machine.

**EDIT4:**
I found information about [Web Deploy Operation Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and postSync setting, but I don't know where to set it, I don't want to edit `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` from MSBuild folder

I need to execute command on remote machine after publish succeeded.

Comment: Hey, I stumbled on this by pure luck. Maybe you should remove one tag and add "asp.net" tag to your question to get more exposure?

Comment: @HamZa thanks for hint. Done.

Comment: Use full path to aspnet_regiis and enclose command in quotes ```<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_r‌​egiis&quot; -pe &quot;appSettings&quot; -site Default -app &quot;/&quot; " />```. Either command is not place properly on console (*try to echo it and see*) or this file can't be overwritten as something is locking.

Comment: Sorry. I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538285/publish-profile-encryption Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After going through your all edits and a bit of research from me , you want to execute the following command after the publish from the Visual Studio

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -site Default -app "/"
```

If i understood right , You can try wrapping the `ItemGroup` in a Target with  `AfterTargets` set to `AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest`

```
<Target Name="executeinHosts" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
         //here would be your path that need to run after the publish
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

So in Your case this is how that part should look:

```
<Target Name="executeinHosts" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
         <path>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -site $(DeployIisAppPath) -app "/"</path>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**Additional Info:**

- `AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest` target works justright before Web Deploy copying files from local to server.
- aspnet_regiis can be run in `<target>` node by `<Exec>`.

*Ex:*

```
<Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connectionStrings $(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp" WorkingDirectory="$(publishUrl)" />
```

Comment: Thank You for reply. I remember I've tried adding `MsDeploySourceManifest` but inside VS I got error about namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`. One additional question, should I put that command inside `path` element inside `MsDeploySourceManifest` or I must escape it somehow?

Comment: @Misiu , possibly try with the Path , if it didn't workout need a way to execute it .

Comment: It worked. `<path>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -site Default -app "/"</path>` please add this into Your answer so that anyone with similar problem will have working solution.

Comment: I was misinformed by that schema warning. One thing missing is getting sine name and path from config instead hard coding them. Do You know how to add them?

Comment: I just noticed in Output window that this command runs twice. I got `Encrypting configuration section... Succeeded!` two times. When I remove that target I get no entries, with single target I got two entries in Output. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Misiu no idea , might be somewhere triggerring twices in your execution , have a keen look into it

Comment: Nothing fance there. I just added that single new target and I'm still Build>Publish from menu. I'll check that in new project. Maybe I have some changes in csproj.

Comment: @Misiu probably MsBUild executing in batches while deploying so ,i'm assuming that time it is executing twice, generally MSbuild will be executing only once thats how functional programming  should work..

Comment: I am trying to do a very similar thing like in this question, but the difference is I  am going to deploy my application to the remote server instead of local IIS using Publish>Web Deploy. But I need to encrypt them before copying them over to a server. But haven't found a way to do it. Any suggestion for web deploy?

Comment: by doing right click to project and selecting the publish profile/pubxml file. As a publish option. The profile created by using this option IIS,FTP,ETC option. @Webruster

Comment: @enterbutton which internally uses the process which i defined in my answer

Comment: @Webruster I am pretty new in this so I am trying to understand. Are you referring `<MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">` by saying process? And 2more questions when this `AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest" ` works in publish life cycle ? Which target is working before copying files to a server? So I need to encrypt them before sending them to a server.

Comment: @Webruster  Just wanted to update here, `AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest` target is worked just like I needed. It's worked just before copying folders over server. BTW I can also able to run the aspnet_regiis by this command `<Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connectionStrings $(ProjectDir)obj\TEST_Debug\Package\PackageTmp" WorkingDirectory="$(publishUrl)" />` rather than using `<MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">`

Comment: @enterbutton means ?

Comment: means that it's working just wanted to add here the things I looked into for other people requires more explanation...