# Publish Profile Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, visual-studio-2015, publish-profiles

I want to encrypt my connection string and app settings. Currently, I have multiple publish profiles with each profile having it's transform.

```
Below is my pubxml file code but for some reason my target with exec command is not getting triggered. Can some one familiar with the subject matter please help!!
```

Thank You in advance.

```
<project toolsversion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.co...">
    <propertygroup>
    <webpublishmethod>FileSystem</webpublishmethod>
    <lastusedbuildconfiguration>Release</lastusedbuildconfiguration>
    <lastusedplatform>Any CPU</lastusedplatform>
    <siteurltolaunchafterpublish/>
    <launchsiteafterpublish>True</launchsiteafterpublish>
    <excludeapp_data>False</excludeapp_data>
    <publishurl>e:\Test_Deployment</publishurl>
    <deleteexistingfiles>False</deleteexistingfiles>
    <msdeployenablewebconfigencryptrule>true</msdeployenablewebconfigencryptrule>

    </propertygroup>
    <target name="CustomPostPublishActions" aftertargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <exec command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe appSettings -app $(publishUrl)/MyProj"/>
    <exec command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connectionStrings $(publishUrl) -prov MyProviderKey"/>
    </target>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make that work, you can try these steps:

1- Create a new Build configuration (under Debug/Release menu go to **Configuration manager..** then on the **Configuration** column create a New configuration).

2- On a Postbuild event (Project properties > Build events > Post build event command line) add something like:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "MyNewBuildConfiguration"(
execute commands in here
)
```

3- Update your profiles for using this Build Configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have multiple profiles so I need to keep $publishurl variable in exec command. How can I do that?